# Custom login in Spring Security 3.2.3

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-security

I have a simple Spring Security configuration with custom login page. The ROLE_ANONYMOUS authority is correctly granted to /pub/login.jsp (see the log below), however the page itself is not being displayed in the web browser, e.g. requesting `http://localhost:8080/pub/login.jsp` shows me the 404 error page with the message "The requested resource (/pub/login.jsp) is not available..".

Do you have any idea what is wrong?

spring-security-context.xml

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/pub/login.jsp*" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

    <form-login login-page="/pub/login.jsp"
                always-use-default-target="true"
                default-target-url='/presence' />                  
    <session-management >
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
    </session-management>
</http>
<authentication-manager>
<authentication-provider>
<user-service>
    <user name="john" password="123" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
    <user name="alex" password="123" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
</user-service>
</authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The login form in login.jsp has been taken from Spring Security examples:

```
<body>
<div class="span8 column">
    <c:url value="/login" var="loginUrl"/>
    <form action="${loginUrl}" method="post">
        <c:if test="${param.error != null}">
            <p>
                Invalid username and password.
            </p>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${param.logout != null}">
            <p>
                You have been logged out.
            </p>
        </c:if>
        <p>
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>
        </p>
        <input type="hidden"
               name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
               value="${_csrf.token}"/>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Log in</button>
    </form>
```

Controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showLoginFailure(@RequestParam(value="loginFailure", required = false) String     loginFailure,  Model model) { ... return pub/login.jsp}
```

LOG information:

```
02.04.2014 09:29:44.517 [FilterChainProxy] [FilterChainProxy.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-2] /pub/login.jsp at position 1 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
02.04.2014 09:29:44.517 [HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] [HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-2] HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
02.04.2014 09:29:44.517 [HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] [HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-2] No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@1dee16c. A new one will be created.
02.04.2014 09:29:44.517 [FilterChainProxy] [FilterChainProxy.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-2] /pub/login.jsp at position 2 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ConcurrentSessionFilter'
02.04.2014 09:29:44.517 [FilterChainProxy] [FilterChainProxy.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-2] /pub/login.jsp at position 3 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
02.04.2014 09:29:44.518 [FilterChainProxy] [FilterChainProxy.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-2] /pub/login.jsp at position 4 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
02.04.2014 09:29:44.518 [FilterChainProxy] [FilterChainProxy.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-2] /pub/login.jsp at position 5 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
02.04.2014 09:29:44.518 [DefaultSavedRequest] [DefaultSavedRequest.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-2] pathInfo: both null (property equals)
02.04.2014 09:29:44.518 [DefaultSavedRequest] [DefaultSavedRequest.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-2] queryString: both null (property equals)
02.04.2014 09:29:44.518 [DefaultSavedRequest] [DefaultSavedRequest.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-2] requestURI: arg1=/; arg2=/pub/login.jsp (property not equals)
02.04.2014 09:29:44.519 [HttpSessionRequestCache] [HttpSessionRequestCache.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-2] saved request doesn't match
02.04.2014 09:29:44.519 [FilterChainProxy] [FilterChainProxy.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-2] /pub/login.jsp at position 6 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
02.04.2014 09:29:44.519 [FilterChainProxy] [FilterChainProxy.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-2] /pub/login.jsp at position 7 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
02.04.2014 09:29:44.519 [AnonymousAuthenticationFilter] [AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-2] Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9054b1a2: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@1c07a: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: FE27BD9B686D9F370C83FB70B76C51A5; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
02.04.2014 09:29:44.519 [FilterChainProxy] [FilterChainProxy.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-2] /pub/login.jsp at position 8 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
02.04.2014 09:29:44.520 [FilterChainProxy] [FilterChainProxy.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-2] /pub/login.jsp at position 9 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
02.04.2014 09:29:44.520 [FilterChainProxy] [FilterChainProxy.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-2] /pub/login.jsp at position 10 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
02.04.2014 09:29:44.520 [AntPathRequestMatcher] [AntPathRequestMatcher.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-2] Checking match of request : '/pub/login.jsp'; against '/pub/login.jsp*'
02.04.2014 09:29:44.520 [FilterSecurityInterceptor] [AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-2] Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /pub/login.jsp; Attributes: [permitAll]
02.04.2014 09:29:44.521 [FilterSecurityInterceptor] [AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-2] Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9054b1a2: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@1c07a: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: FE27BD9B686D9F370C83FB70B76C51A5; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
02.04.2014 09:29:44.522 [FilterSecurityInterceptor] [AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-2] Authorization successful
02.04.2014 09:29:44.522 [FilterSecurityInterceptor] [AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-2] RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
02.04.2014 09:29:44.522 [FilterChainProxy] [FilterChainProxy.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-2] /pub/login.jsp reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
02.04.2014 09:29:44.522 [HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] [HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-2] SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
02.04.2014 09:29:44.523 [ExceptionTranslationFilter] [ExceptionTranslationFilter.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-2] Chain processed normally
02.04.2014 09:29:44.523 [SecurityContextPersistenceFilter] [SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-2] SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
02.04.2014 09:29:44.702 [FilterChainProxy] [FilterChainProxy.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-4] /pub/login.jsp at position 1 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
02.04.2014 09:29:44.702 [HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] [HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-4] HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
02.04.2014 09:29:44.702 [HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] [HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-4] No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@1dee16c. A new one will be created.
02.04.2014 09:29:44.702 [FilterChainProxy] [FilterChainProxy.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-4] /pub/login.jsp at position 2 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ConcurrentSessionFilter'
02.04.2014 09:29:44.702 [FilterChainProxy] [FilterChainProxy.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-4] /pub/login.jsp at position 3 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
02.04.2014 09:29:44.702 [FilterChainProxy] [FilterChainProxy.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-4] /pub/login.jsp at position 4 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
02.04.2014 09:29:44.702 [FilterChainProxy] [FilterChainProxy.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-4] /pub/login.jsp at position 5 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
02.04.2014 09:29:44.702 [DefaultSavedRequest] [DefaultSavedRequest.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-4] pathInfo: both null (property equals)
02.04.2014 09:29:44.703 [DefaultSavedRequest] [DefaultSavedRequest.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-4] queryString: both null (property equals)
02.04.2014 09:29:44.703 [DefaultSavedRequest] [DefaultSavedRequest.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-4] requestURI: arg1=/; arg2=/pub/login.jsp (property not equals)
02.04.2014 09:29:44.703 [HttpSessionRequestCache] [HttpSessionRequestCache.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-4] saved request doesn't match
02.04.2014 09:29:44.703 [FilterChainProxy] [FilterChainProxy.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-4] /pub/login.jsp at position 6 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
02.04.2014 09:29:44.703 [FilterChainProxy] [FilterChainProxy.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-4] /pub/login.jsp at position 7 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
02.04.2014 09:29:44.703 [AnonymousAuthenticationFilter] [AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-4] Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9054b1a2: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@1c07a: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: FE27BD9B686D9F370C83FB70B76C51A5; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
02.04.2014 09:29:44.703 [FilterChainProxy] [FilterChainProxy.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-4] /pub/login.jsp at position 8 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
02.04.2014 09:29:44.703 [FilterChainProxy] [FilterChainProxy.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-4] /pub/login.jsp at position 9 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
02.04.2014 09:29:44.703 [FilterChainProxy] [FilterChainProxy.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-4] /pub/login.jsp at position 10 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
02.04.2014 09:29:44.704 [AntPathRequestMatcher] [AntPathRequestMatcher.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-4] Checking match of request : '/pub/login.jsp'; against '/pub/login.jsp*'
02.04.2014 09:29:44.704 [FilterSecurityInterceptor] [AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-4] Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /pub/login.jsp; Attributes: [permitAll]
02.04.2014 09:29:44.704 [FilterSecurityInterceptor] [AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-4] Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9054b1a2: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@1c07a: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: FE27BD9B686D9F370C83FB70B76C51A5; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
02.04.2014 09:29:44.705 [FilterSecurityInterceptor] [AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-4] Authorization successful
02.04.2014 09:29:44.705 [FilterSecurityInterceptor] [AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-4] RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
02.04.2014 09:29:44.705 [FilterChainProxy] [FilterChainProxy.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-4] /pub/login.jsp reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
02.04.2014 09:29:44.706 [HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] [HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-4] SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
02.04.2014 09:29:44.706 [ExceptionTranslationFilter] [ExceptionTranslationFilter.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-4] Chain processed normally
02.04.2014 09:29:44.706 [SecurityContextPersistenceFilter] [SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-4] SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Comment: Did you try just `/login`? That's what your `RequestMapping` and the JSTL tag say. Spring knows to add `.jsp`, `.vm`, `.html` or whatever to the end to find the template for the view.

Comment: For /login my controller showLoginFailure() is launched. I was hoping to be directed to the login.jsp. Maybe I should remove the controller?

Comment: @luksmir Do you have this `/pub/login.jsp` path inside `web-inf`?

Comment: @sankrish Yes, it exist. However, The dispatcherservlet says:
'[RequestMappingHandlerMapping] [AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java] [DEBUG] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-3] Did not find handler method for [/views/Login.html]
[PageNotFound] [DispatcherServlet.java] [WARN ] ["http-apr-8080"-exec-3] No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/views/Login.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'Spring Dispatcher' '. Perhaps that's the reason?